# Script to modify files inside WAR

Tags: war, jython, resourcebundle

I need to update the resource files inside a WAR for different environments (eg Database info)

So i need to write a script which will update these files inside the WAR. Please let me know if the above is possible using Jython Scripts or Suggest any other script where this is achievable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `.war` file format is simply the same as `.zip` file format you can use `zipfile` module to work with those files. Unfortunately `ZipFile` objects do not allow modifying files in existing `.zip` files, so you will have to copy all files from source `.war` and modify content of selected file. Example:

```
def modify_war(war):
    if os.path.exists(war):
        zf_in = zipfile.ZipFile(war, 'r')
        zf_out = zipfile.ZipFile(war[:-4] + '_new.war', 'w')
        try:
            for item in zf_in.infolist():
                content = zf_in.read(item.filename)
                if item.filename == 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF':
                    content += '\nModified-By: mn\n'
                zf_out.writestr(item, content)
        finally:
            zf_in.close()
            zf_out.close()
```